# Creating nested triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently working with MySQL databases and I am trying to create a nested trigger. But I am having trouble and errors. I have tried many things but I cannot seem to figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. You would find my script for tables and trigger below.

```
    CREATE TABLE co_op_members (
    MemberID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Description varchar(255),
    BusinessName varchar(255),
    Date date,
    ContactName varchar(255),
    Email varchar(255),
    Phone int,
    Address varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (MemberID)

);


CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255),
    Email varchar(255),
    Location varchar(255),
    StartDate date,
    DeliveryAddress varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId)

);

CREATE TABLE Message (
   MessageId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   CustomerId int ,
   AepcMemberId int,
   Message varchar(255),
   Date date,
   PRIMARY KEY (MessageId),
   FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId),
   FOREIGN KEY (AepcMemberId) REFERENCES co_op_members(MemberID)

);

CREATE TABLE Equipment (
   ItemId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   StyleName varchar(255),
   ItemName varchar(255),
   PackSize int,
   Description varchar(255),
   MemberId int,
   Price int,
   PriceDate date,
   UniteShippingDate date,
   UnitShippingCost int,
   PRIMARY KEY (ItemId),
   FOREIGN KEY (MemberId) REFERENCES co_op_members(MemberId)

);

CREATE TABLE Equipmentorder (

   OrderId int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
   CustomerId int,
   AepcMemberId int,
   ShippingDate date,
   OrderStatus varchar(255),
   OrderDate date,
   CourierName varchar(255),
    ItemId int,
   ShippingCost float,

   ShippingReferenceNo int,
   PRIMARY KEY (OrderId),
   FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId),
   FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES Equipment(ItemId)


);
```

And here's the trigger script:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER after_customer_order_plced
AFTER INSERT
ON message FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CREATE TRIGGER after_members_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON members FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.customers IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO message(memberId, message)
        VALUES(new.id,CONCAT('Hi ', NEW.name, ', hello new message.'));

END
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You can't run a `CREATE` or any other type of DDL statement or any statement that causes an [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html) in the body of a trigger. I have never heard of a "nested trigger." What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a messaging system so that if a customer has a message, it could be stored in the 'Message' table with the message. I have to test the script later so that when I run it, it should allow me to type a message and then store that message in the 'Message' table.